# AppEngine/Datastore: Best way to retrieve since ancestor query returns everything recursively

Tags: google-app-engine, go, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

When I do a `get()` with an ancestor constraint, it seems like I get all entities for that ancestor key and all ancestors that it is parent to.

In this case, I am using ancestral relationships to represent a homogenous tree (all nodes represented by the same kind; every level is immediately consistent). All of the IDs I am using are globally unique and I have the parent-ID written on each entity (in addition to it being in the ancestor path).

Since the by-ancestor retrieval returns too much data (all levels at and below rather than just the immediate level; The documentation doesn't mention this and a couple of others eccentricities), I'll need to add a filter to make sure I just get back the current level.

So, the question is whether there's a difference in efficiency to do a `ancestor().filter()` versus just `filter()` since these both produce the same results for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Word of advice - Make sure you test on GAE. You may need to re-consider using ancestry for such tree. I had a similar tree (but with different entity kinds at different levels). I found that doing just many `get_by_id()` with just a few writes in concurrent requests was causing lots of data contention exceptions on the entity root (and poor performance) when running on GAE - everything appeared fine on the local devserver. Right now I'm refactoring my app to drop the ancestry between levels, one by one, I see great perf improvements but still get contention exceptions - I'll drop all of them.

Comment: "contention exceptions" meaning an irreconcilable consistency problem at the GAE level? Why would you assume that this was a curse of the use-case rather than a bug in your implementation? The problem is that, at this time, I preload/sync the tree at the first request. None of it is dynamic though I've left room for it to be at some point in the future (presupposing a theoretical change in the preference of the userbase). In order to establish whether the stored information matches the representation within the configuration tree I need it to be consistent. Thoughts?

Comment: Disregard the second part. It's not worth it. This data will always be more static than not (low rate of change). Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I don't mean the irreconcilable ones - those occur on write ops and are caught by the devserver. I'm talking about randomly occuring `TransactionFailedError: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again. entity group key:` where the key points to the root of the entity group and the stack trace indicates `get_by_id()` calls for items 3 or 4 levels down from that root entity. The occurence rate depends on the overall rate of requests doing writes on that entity group. Might not be an issue for your app, if you're doing just reads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `filter()` is eventually consistent, whereas `ancestor().filter()` is strongly consistent.

As you mentioned, you'll need to filter by an indexed a property to just get a particular level of the tree back.